# how can I deploy/publish my asp.net MVC application to online

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

how can I deploy/publish my asp.net MVC application made in visual studio 2015 .net version 4.5 ,and sql server database 2016 database using localhost (.)  with windows authentication   ...to online ..so it can be accessed to everyone ....with code updations and sql server edition..thank you

Comment: Hi Faux.  This question is really too broad for this format.  There are many complexities to your question that need to be learned by reading.  Check out some tutorials about deploying a website to IIS.

Comment: Hi luke ,,is it possible using the localhost sql server....and where to publish whether to iis , azure or godaddy

Comment: It's possible to host it locally on your own machine, if that's what you mean?  You'll have to ensure that your ISP allows you to open the relevant ports etc.  I wouldn't recommend this personally as home broadband connections aren't generally designed for decent bandwidth/latency outbound.  I'd recommend Azure or AWS to someone familiar with ASP.NET/IIS.  But those in themselves involve a steep learning curve.  I'd try a host like Godaddy or another host that has IIS set up ready for you.

Comment: Firstly: windows authentication doesn't work on the internet. I suggest the easiest way to publish your app is to use Azure or AWS to create some cloud servers and publish to them

Comment: thanks nick ...have to tried azure ..is it good

Answer (score 0):

You can host your application using IIS. IIS can be setup in any machine.

> **Steps :**
>
> 1. Install IIS
> 2. Open IIS manager by entering `inetmgr` in Run(win+R)
> 3. Add website by browisng to its location to the published website location. (Hope you know how to publish a website in visual studio)
> 4. Edit the web config file to configure the sql server credentials(Sql db could be hosted separately or in the same machine)
> 5. Right click the website in IIS Manager and click start.
> 6. Click browse to view the website
> 7. You could either access the site by `localhost:portnumber` or by specifying `IP:port number` in settings of the website in IIS manager
> 8. You can access the website from mobile or external devices if you select public IP for your website. Incase you're connected to a local network, then the website could be accessed only from within your work place. Discuss with your network admin about exposing your server to public by providing a public IP address, if you're on local network.

Feel free to revert if you have more doubts.

Comment: hi ViVi for the help ,,,after performing this will my machine behave as web and databse server

Comment: You can host the sql in the same machine or on another machine. Accordingly you should update your web.config file to reflect the changes. @faux

Comment: Hi ViVi ,,but I have local host db ( . )   do I need to do any configuration for this

Comment: I am not sure about that. I think no change is required. If db connection is failing then you might need to udpate the instancename of sql server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a VPS or DS us can use this [Article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploying-your-Asp-Net-mvc-5-app-to-iis-8/) it teaches localy but it is same with real VPS or DS

Also if have a Host you should publish your project on your system and upload it to your Host Provider and make backup of your SQL Server Database and set your host provider IP in `Web.Config`.